# Using child objects to configure a parent

Tags: reactjs

I have an javascript object that requires configuration. Configuration
comes in the form of calling some optional functions on the object after
it has been created.

In React it seems reasonable to model this with a parent/child
relationship:

```
<Parent>
  <ChildConfigOption/>
</Parent>
```

In the parent's componentDidMount I am using the DOM element to create a javascript object.
After creating the object, I add it to this (this.foo = myobj) and I am
trying to expose this.foo to the child via context so the child can call
the method to configure the parent.

The difficulty is that in the child this.context.foo is undefined. A
little digging into the lifecycle between the parent and child suggests why:

```
ParentComponent - getDefaultProps
ChildComponent - getDefaultProps
ParentComponent - getInitialState
ParentComponent - componentWillMount
ParentComponent - render
ChildComponent - getInitialState
ChildComponent - componentWillMount
ChildComponent - render
ChildComponent - componentDidMount <--- Try to access this.context.foo: it's undefined
ParentComponent - componentDidMount <--- obj created, assigned to this.foo which is shared via the context.
```

The question behind all this is, with the constraint that the object can only be created once the DOM node exists (ie: in the parent componentDidMount): How do I do this?

Is there a better approach for this?

Comment: May be silly, but did you use `getChildContext` in the parent to create the shared object?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the information you need? Why do you need the DOM element?

Comment: It's a canvas based map. I can only create the map object by passing a DOM element to use as the container. Since it can't be instantiated without the DOM element it looks like I am stuck creating it in componentDidMount

Comment: @nickos: Always worth asking. Yes, I did do getChildContext in the parent.

Comment: @mikewilliamson Why can't you just pass the DOM element as a prop to the child?

Comment: You could use `forceUpdate()` to force a re-render, but that's typically discouraged in the docs. Another option would be to keep track of your DOM object through state, grab it once it exists & `setState()` to make that data available: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNgLmb. I can add this as an answer, but I'd rather be positive that you want to be using context here as it's a little weird.

Comment: @BradColthurst: I thought setState in the componentDidMount was bad?

Comment: @Aaron: The DOM node is needed to create the js object. Once it exists I need to create the object and somehow get it to the child.

Comment: It's typically considered bad practice yes. As far as I'm aware it's only normally done when you need access to rendered HTML elements for your logic, since componentDidMount() is where those rendered HTML elements are. See: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/494. That demo I posted should actually have a conditional to keep `setState` from having an infinite loop on component mounts. My bad.

Comment: @mikewilliamson I don't follow. You create the DOM element in parent, right? You create the "JS object" in child, right? So you can simply create the DOM element in parent and pass it to child through props. Maybe you should show your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue this is *not* very idiomatic. Why not simply have a property for configuration?

If you need to update the config, you can simply pass a function down to the child, which can then notify the parent of the change, who will re-render.

```
onOptionChange (configOption) {
  this.setState(configOption)
}
...
<Parent config={this.state.configOption}>
  <Child onOptionChange={this.onOptionChange}/>
</Parent>
```